# Dropdown retrieving trouble

Tags: javascript, html

This is the script of my code.The Script is working fine but the problem arises in html. First of all check out this script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     $(".form-control").change(function()
     {
      var id=$(this).val();
      var dataString = 'id='+ id;

      $.ajax
      ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "php/get_child.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html)
       {
          $("#statee").html(html);

       } 
       });
      });




    });
    </script>
```

this is the code which does not work

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Child Category :</label> <select name="state" **id="statee"**>
<option selected="selected">--Select Child Category--</option>
</select>
```

whereas it works

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Child Category :</label> <select name="state" **class="statee"**>
<option selected="selected">--Select Child Category--</option>
</select>
```

I want to run it using id not class method.Please help me in doing that

Comment: can you check for error logs in the console.

Comment: You forgot to tag `jQuery`, and you really need to learn about the difference between JavaScript (which is correct) and Java (which is not).

Answer (score 0):

**Why id not working?**

Id is an unique .It's only select `idname` of the first element .Multiple same `id` is there in your html.kindly check `sameid`*(check `id=statee` only once there in your html)* name already present or not in your html elements.If is present already change the `id` name with different one .

**whereas it works?**

class select the all element with contains same `classname`
`class` is better one for multiple element.but if you need only id use like this

```
$("[id='statee']").html(html);
```